# Understanding the percolate up and down functions in Heaps (Priority Queues)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, heap

I am having some problems with the code for percolate up and down in a min-heap (the smallest key on top). My biggest gripe is with the for loops of these two code snippets, which is causing me to not understand the rest of the code...

```
int hole = ++currentSize;
Comparable copy = x;

array[ 0 ] = std::move( copy ); //in the books implementation the zero 
//index is kept empty, is this to create a temporary place for the added element?
for( ; x < array[ hole / 2 ]; hole /= 2 ) //my biggest problem is understanding this for loop!!!
    array[ hole ] = std::move( array[ hole / 2 ] ); //what does this do?
array[ hole ] = std::move( array[ 0 ] );
```

I don't understand the for loop here. It might have to do with the relationships like the parent of i'th index is in i/2 and so on, but I am clueless about this. This is to insert an element to the heap. Any help in laying out the meaning of the code is appreciated.

Then there is percolate down for the findMin method, which again I don't understand the code for.

```
/**
    * Internal method to percolate down in the heap.
    * hole is the index at which the percolate begins.
    */
void percolateDown( int hole )
{
    int child;
    Comparable tmp = std::move( array[ hole ] );

    for( ; hole * 2 <= currentSize; hole = child ) //not clear with this for loop!!!
{
    child = hole * 2;
    if( child != currentSize && array[ child + 1 ] < array[ child ] )
    ++child;
    if( array[ child ] < tmp )
    array[ hole ] = std::move( array[ child ] );
    else
        break;
    }
    array[ hole ] = std::move( tmp );
    } //somewhat understood, except the for loop...
```

Mainly the for loop, but also what part of the code does what? Apologies if there is any amateurishness in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It is as you say: the parent of element `i` is located at `i/2`. What the code does is insert a "hole", which will be where the new element is placed. The line in the for loop:

`array[ hole ] = std::move( array[ hole / 2 ] );`

is moving the parent to the location of the child (which was the "hole"). So what we're basically doing is the following

```
while (element being moved up < parent)
    move parent to current index
    current index = index of parent
place element at current index
```

The other piece of code does the opposite. It's a bit more complicated, because while each element has only one parent, it may have two children. The first is located at `i * 2`, the second at `i * 2 + 1`. First we check if the element even has children (`child != currentSize`). We only want to swap the parent with the child if the child is smaller. So we look which child is the smallest (`array[ child + 1 ] < array[ child ]`). We compare that child with its parent: if it is smaller, we exchange them and continue, otherwise we are done. Finally we place the element we were moving back in the "hole".